# CoC not sending autocomplete request message to language server

Tags: c++, vim, vim-plugin, neovim, coc.nvim

My nvim autocomplete window is not coming up when editing C++ code.
I've been trying to follow this [debugging guideline](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/wiki/Debug-language-server) but I haven't had much success. I'm using the Kythe language server configured as follows in `coc-settings.json`:

```
{
    "languageserver": {
        "kythe": {
            "command": "/full/path/omitted/kythe_languageserver",
            "filetypes": ["python", "go", "java", "cpp", "cc", "c++", "proto"],
            "trace.server" : "verbose"
        }
    }
}
```

When opening a C++ file and running `:CocList services`, I can see that the language server has started:

```
languageserver.kythe [running] python, go, java, cpp, cc, c++, proto
```

And indeed in the `:CocCommand workspace.showOutput`, there are messages indicating a successful initialization:

```
[Trace - 4:45:05 PM] Received response 'initialize - (0)' in 264ms.
Result: {
    "capabilities": {
        "textDocumentSync": 1,
        "hoverProvider": true,
        "definitionProvider": true,
        "referencesProvider": true
    }
}
```

One thought, is there a missing capability here that is required for autocomplete to come up? In any case, when I edit the file and try to, for example, type `std::` expecting some form of autocompletion for that namespace, nothing happens and the only messages sent to the language server seem to be as follows:

```
[Trace - 4:45:47 PM] Sending notification 'textDocument/didChange'.
Params: {
    "textDocument": {
        "uri": "[redacted]",
        "version": 4
    },
    "contentChanges": [
        {
            "text": "[redacted]"
        }
    ]
}
```

From my limited knowledge, I'm pretty sure that autocompletion also requires a different message type to be sent to the language server, no? `textDocument/didChange` seems to be only for updating the state.

**Edit:** Full set of requested capabilities by nvim:

```
 "capabilities": {
        "workspace": {
            "applyEdit": true,
            "workspaceEdit": {
                "documentChanges": true,
                "resourceOperations": [
                    "create",
                    "rename",
                    "delete"
                ],
                "failureHandling": "textOnlyTransactional"
            },
            "didChangeConfiguration": {
                "dynamicRegistration": true
            },
            "didChangeWatchedFiles": {
                "dynamicRegistration": true
            },
            "symbol": {
                "dynamicRegistration": true,
                "symbolKind": {
                    "valueSet": [
                        1,
                        2,
                        3,
                        4,
                        5,
                        6,
                        7,
                        8,
                        9,
                        10,
                        11,
                        12,
                        13,
                        14,
                        15,
                        16,
                        17,
                        18,
                        19,
                        20,
                        21,
                        22,
                        23,
                        24,
                        25,
                        26
                    ]
                },
                "tagSupport": {
                    "valueSet": [
                        1
                    ]
                }
            },
            "executeCommand": {
                "dynamicRegistration": true
            },
            "configuration": true,
            "workspaceFolders": true
        },
        "textDocument": {
            "publishDiagnostics": {
                "relatedInformation": true,
                "versionSupport": false,
                "tagSupport": {
                    "valueSet": [
                        1,
                        2
                    ]
                }
            },
            "synchronization": {
                "dynamicRegistration": true,
                "willSave": true,
                "willSaveWaitUntil": true,
                "didSave": true
            },
            "completion": {
                "dynamicRegistration": true,
                "contextSupport": true,
                "completionItem": {
                    "snippetSupport": true,
                    "commitCharactersSupport": true,
                    "documentationFormat": [
                        "markdown",
                        "plaintext"
                    ],
                    "deprecatedSupport": true,
                    "preselectSupport": true
                },
                "completionItemKind": {
                    "valueSet": [
                        1,
                        2,
                        3,
                        4,
                        5,
                        6,
                        7,
                        8,
                        9,
                        10,
                        11,
                        12,
                        13,
                        14,
                        15,
                        16,
                        17,
                        18,
                        19,
                        20,
                        21,
                        22,
                        23,
                        24,
                        25
                    ]
                }
            },
            "hover": {
                "dynamicRegistration": true,
                "contentFormat": [
                    "markdown",
                    "plaintext"
                ]
            },
            "signatureHelp": {
                "dynamicRegistration": true,
                "signatureInformation": {
                    "documentationFormat": [
                        "markdown",
                        "plaintext"
                    ],
                    "parameterInformation": {
                        "labelOffsetSupport": true
                    }
                }
            },
            "definition": {
                "dynamicRegistration": true
            },
            "references": {
                "dynamicRegistration": true
            },
            "documentHighlight": {
                "dynamicRegistration": true
            },
            "documentSymbol": {
                "dynamicRegistration": true,
                "symbolKind": {
                    "valueSet": [
                        1,
                        2,
                        3,
                        4,
                        5,
                        6,
                        7,
                        8,
                        9,
                        10,
                        11,
                        12,
                        13,
                        14,
                        15,
                        16,
                        17,
                        18,
                        19,
                        20,
                        21,
                        22,
                        23,
                        24,
                        25,
                        26
                    ]
                },
                "hierarchicalDocumentSymbolSupport": true,
                "tagSupport": {
                    "valueSet": [
                        1
                    ]
                }
            },
            "codeAction": {
                "dynamicRegistration": true,
                "isPreferredSupport": true,
                "codeActionLiteralSupport": {
                    "codeActionKind": {
                        "valueSet": [
                            "",
                            "quickfix",
                            "refactor",
                            "refactor.extract",
                            "refactor.inline",
                            "refactor.rewrite",
                            "source",
                            "source.organizeImports"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            "codeLens": {
                "dynamicRegistration": true
            },
            "formatting": {
                "dynamicRegistration": true
            },
            "rangeFormatting": {
                "dynamicRegistration": true
            },
            "onTypeFormatting": {
                "dynamicRegistration": true
            },
            "rename": {
                "dynamicRegistration": true,
                "prepareSupport": true
            },
            "documentLink": {
                "dynamicRegistration": true,
                "tooltipSupport": true
            },
            "typeDefinition": {
                "dynamicRegistration": true
            },
            "implementation": {
                "dynamicRegistration": true
            },
            "declaration": {
                "dynamicRegistration": true
            },
            "colorProvider": {
                "dynamicRegistration": true
            },
            "foldingRange": {
                "dynamicRegistration": true,
                "rangeLimit": 5000,
                "lineFoldingOnly": true
            },
            "selectionRange": {
                "dynamicRegistration": true
            }
        },
        "window": {
            "workDoneProgress": true
        }
    },
```

Comment: What's the `capabilities` in `Sending request 'initialize - (0)'`? You can get this at the begin output of `:CocCommand workspace.showOutput`.

Comment: I've added an edit with the requested capabilities

Comment: I don't have an env to try Kythe. From the logs, coc sends request to server with completion/definition/x/y/z capabilities, the server responses hover/definition/references only, that means Kythe can only do hover/definition/references with LSP support, so there is no completions.

Comment: Does Kythe support code completions? Can you make it works with VSCode + Kythe?https://github.com/kythe/kythe/tree/master/kythe/typescript/languageserver/vscode-extension

Comment: From https://github.com/kythe/kythe/blob/master/kythe/go/languageserver/languageserver.go , Kythe only support hover/definition/references by now.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kythe language server does not support auto complete capabilities as of yet.